# R Loop for matched data.table columns

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, apply

I am really struggling to create a function that runs a model where all the variables `a`, `b`, `d`, `g` & `N` have multiple versions as shown in the data.table below which I've named `crm`:

```
crm = data.table(
  East = 26500,
  North = c(115000, 120000, 125000, 130000, 135000, 140000), 
  rain = c(1049.61, 1114.31, 1361.61, 1407.2, 1499.56, 1654.13), 
  crop = 'Wheat', area = c(0.1718, 0.1629, 0.1082, 0.0494, 0.02, 0.004), 
  rn = c("10007", "10018", "10023", "10024", "10025", "10026"), 
  N1 = 184.262648839489, N2 = 180.312874871521, N3 = 178.615847839997,
  N4 = 182.531626054579, a1 = 0.186117715072018, a2 = -0.0232731908915799,
  a3 = 0.227017532149122, a4 = 0.162943230565506, b1 = 0.000478900233700419,
  b2 = 0.000787931973696371, b3 = 0.000458478256537521, b4 = 0.000517304324750896,
  d1 = -0.000328164576390286, d2 = -0.000112122093240884, d3 = 0.000112702113716146,
  d4 = 7.40875908059628e-05, g1 = 4.04709473710477e-06, g2 = 3.68724096485995e-06,
  g3 = 3.47214450131546e-06, g4 = 3.55825543257538e-06, key = 'rn'
)
```

What I'm trying to do is run the function below to calculate a value for `lnN` and put it into a column that has the same number in the heading as the variables entered into the model. I.e. Using `a1`,`b1`,`d1`,`g1` & `N1` will produce the column `lnN1` and so on for all the 2s, 3s and 4s.

```
n <- 1:4
cols <- paste0("lnN",n)
for(i in 1:length(n)){
crm[,(cols) := lapply(.SD ,function (x) {
  N = crm[,7+i]
  a = crm[,11+i]
  b = crm[,15+i]
  d = crm[,19+i]
  g = crm[,23+i]
a + (b*crm[,rain]) + (g*N) + (d*crm[,rain]*N)}), .SDcols = paste0("N",n)]
```

}

I've yet to find an example anywhere on how to accomplish this. I've tried using `mapply`but I can't see how to iterate mapply through all the iterations of each variable. Thank you for your help!

Comment: "I've yet to find an example anywhere on how to accomplish this." In this case, I think that is a hint that your data structure is flawed. I find it quite hard to understand what you're attempting since you overwrite `(cols) :=` four times, which does not look like a useful thing to do. Anyway, I'd start with `melt(crm, meas=patterns("^N", "^a", "^b", "^d", "^g"), value.name=c("N","a","b","d","g"))` and find a way to work from there rather than fiddling with column numbers, which is I think (?) what you're doing here.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the suggestion. I can't think of how else to structure my data as I need to generate multivariate data for each variable as part of a Monte Carlo method to get an uncertainty value. I will look at your suggestion and see what I can do.

Comment: I'd second what @Frank said, to think about as you iterate through your analysis (but `"^N"` might be something like `"^N[0-9]"` to avoid picking up `North`).  Once you do that you can apply your formula by `dd[, lnN:=.(a + (b*rain) + (g*N) + (d*rain*N))]` and carry on with your analysis using `group_by` as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
library(dplyr)
cbind(crm, do.call(cbind, 
  lapply(1:4, function(x) {
    select(crm, c(contains(as.character(x)), rain)) %>% 
      setnames(gsub("[0-9]", "", names(.))) %>%
      transmute(lnN = a + (b*rain) + (g*N) + (d*rain*N)) %>%
      setnames(paste0("lnN", x))
  })
))
```

The main idea is, for each number, select only the columns that contain the number (and also `rain`), rename the columns to remove the numbers, apply the formula, rename the resulting column to append the number, and then `cbind` the result onto the original table.

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't seem to be creating any `lnN` columns at the end of the data.table but I can see the logic in the code. I'll have a play with it and  see what I've done wrong!

Comment: Works fine on my machine... did you assign the output to an name? I.e. `output <- cbind(crm, do.call(cbind, ...` or to the original object `crm <- cbind(crm...`.

Comment: Oh dear... I'll chalk that up to it being a long day! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So having gone and looked at the comments above and realized there could be issues when trying to change the number of iterations into the thousands as both Frank and Weihuang suggested I reconsidered how I structured my data.

What I did instead was to leave the randomly generated matrices of variables as separate dataframes. `e` contains multivariate random values for `a`, `b`, `g` & `d` with `N` (now called `Nit`) in `rnm`. So `crm` now only has the first six columns. The code looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:n){
  a = e[1,i]
  b = e[2,i]
  g = e[3,i]
  d = e[4,i]
Nit = rnm[i]
bob = a + (b*crm$rain) + (g*Nit) + (d*crm$rain*Nit)
data.y <- cbind(data.y, bob)
}
crm <- cbind(crm, data.y)
names(crm)[c(7:n)] = names(bobs)
```

For each iteration of 1:n, it reads the `i` value of each parameter (all the 1s, all the 2s, etc.) and places it into the model and creates a column called `bob`. `bob` is then merged into an empty data frame that I created before the function (`data.y`). This loops until the desired number of loops is achieved.

I then used `cbind` to merge the two together before renaming all the `bob` columns sequentially by using the names stored in a data frame `bobs` that contains a list of column headings numbered `bob.1` to `bob.n` that is read in from a `.csv` file I produced in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `melt`-and-`dcast` (`recast`) version leveraging the [newly implemented](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2568) functionality of `melt` for `patterns` to utilize provided names. See the [Installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for instructions as this is currently a feature in development.

```
library(data.table) 1.10.5+
# create character version of 1:N (Number of output columns)
N = paste0(seq_len(length(grep('^b', names(crm)))))
# join crm to a melt & recast version of itself using rain as 
#   the join key (note this will fail if the amount of rain may
#   not be unique -- in this case, we should include some ID in
#   id.vars, like rn, and adjust accordingly)
crm = crm[crm[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'rain', 
                      measure.vars = patterns(N = '^N[0-9]', a = '^a[0-9]', 
                                              b = '^b', d = '^d', g = '^g'))
               # use the formula to generate ln
               ][ , ln := a + b*rain + g * N + d * rain * N
                  # reshape wide
                  ][ , dcast(.SD, rain ~ variable, value.var = 'ln')
                     # rename the columns here
                     ][ , setnames(.SD, N, paste0('ln', N))],
          on = 'rain']

# by-reference version
crm[crm[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'rain', 
                measure.vars = patterns(N = '^N[0-9]', a = '^a[0-9]', 
                                        b = '^b', d = '^d', g = '^g'))
         # use the formula to generate ln
         ][ , ln := a + b*rain + g * N + d * rain * N
            # reshape wide
            ][ , dcast(.SD, rain ~ variable, value.var = 'ln')],
    # mget tends to be sort of slow, which is why I used the
    #   assign-by-copy approach first above; in larger examples,
    #   this slow-down may be outweighed by the cost of copying
    paste0('ln', N) := mget(N), on = 'rain']
```